# Pytorch, Pre-trained model: How to use feature and classifier at the same time

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I'm using vgg16 extracting image feature vector. I want to get 1*1*4096 vector from the 2nd-to-last layer.

[image]

My code:

```
def get_model():
    model = models.vgg16(pretrained=True)#.features[:].classifier[:4]
    model = model.eval()
    # model.cuda()  # send the model to GPU, DO NOT include this line if you haven't a GPU
    return model
```

But I can only get 1*1*1000 vector from the last layer.

I know how to use `feathers` and `classifier`, but I don't know how to use them at the same time.

use classifier only:

[image: use classifier only]

use feathers only:

[image: use feathers only]

use them at the same time:

[image: use them at the same time]

log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/sunji/PycharmProjects/image_cluster_pytorch/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    model = calc.get_model()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/sunji/PycharmProjects/image_cluster_pytorch/imagecluster/calc.py", line 17, in get_model
    model = models.vgg16(pretrained=True).features[:].classifier[:4]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 771, in __getattr__
    raise ModuleAttributeError("'{}' object has no attribute '{}'".format(
torch.nn.modules.module.ModuleAttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'classifier'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've find the solution myself.

Sorry for bothering to Stack overflow.

here is the code:

```
def get_model():
    model = models.vgg16(pretrained=True)
    model.features = model.features[:]
    model.classifier = model.classifier[:4]

    model = model.eval()
    # model.cuda()  # send the model to GPU, DO NOT include this line if you haven't a GPU
    return model
```

result:

[image]

I think this is the right answer.